# what is resourcename of the person in google api and how to get it

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I am trying to get the user location using google api

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

The above link tells me to give resourcename of person but I dont know how to get the resourcename of a person, and how to get it?

Answer (score 2):

I exhort you to read the whole documentation since the answer is there. As you can see [**here**](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people), the `resourceName` value is:

> The resource name for the person, assigned by the server. An ASCII string with a max length of 27 characters, in the form of people/person_id.

Therefore, in order to get the `resourceName` of people, you need to get a list of the people you have connections with by using the method described **[here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list)**. That method will return a response that looks like this:

```
{


"connections": [
    {
      "resourceName": "people/c4975894400662151399",
      "etag": "%EgYBAgMGGCvT1UyNGZxV0hZPQ==",
      "metadata": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "type": "CONTACT",
            "id": "424762b0ee1ef",
            "etag": "#724fqWHY=",
            "updateTime": "2017-07-29T13:00:33.607002Z"
          }
        ],
        "objectType": "PERSON"
      },
      "names": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "source": {
              "type": "CONTACT",
              "id": "424762b0ee1ef"
            }
          },
          "displayName": "User One",
          "familyName": "One",
          "givenName": "User",
          "displayNameLastFirst": "One, User"
        }
      ],
      "photos": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "source": {
              "type": "CONTACT",
              "id": "424762bc0d0ee1ef"
            }
          },
          "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMWA/AAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAA/4252r5MyReBVCg-JHqUZby0PuQkKAVcQ____________RieL7______8B/s0/photo.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "urls": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "source": {
              "type": "CONTACT",
              "id": "424762b0ee1ef"
            }
          },
          "value": "http://www.google.com/profiles/114002589440066215139",
          "type": "profile",
          "formattedType": "Profile"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": "^CAAQk5r4hNorGncKTQAQwA0ICEAFIhrWIy7a31QJQAlokZTc0YWU0OGYtYWQ4ZC00MThlLWI3MjAtYjE4MTczYzRhNGFkEAIaJGU3NGFlNDhmLWFkOGQtNDE4ZS1iNzIwLWIxODE3M2M0YTRhZA",
  "totalPeople": 94,
  "totalItems": 94
}
```

The above only shows the result for one people resource since I limited the paging results to 1, but hopefully it will give you an idea. After you get the `resourceName`, you should be able to use the method https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get.

Comment: Bro Thanks for your answer, actually I am implementing google login, I want  to get the user's location, not his connection... please help me bro

Comment: @vSugumar Was not that already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409632/how-to-get-user-location-information-using-google-client-api ?